# Confirmation of application of ANCOVA in oceanography

Tags: r, anova, ancova, ecology

Can somebody please confirm this application of an ANCOVA in oceanography?

I measured a biological variable of a marine organism at two time steps (dark blue and light blue in the figure), biological variable in the figure on the x-axis. The y-axis is depth at which the organism was found.

For the actual ANCOVA the biological variable was y, the dependent variable of course. (The figure is like that since we always plot depth as y in oceanography, sorry for that and the ugly handmade axis).

Now, I want to show that the two linear regression (slopes) are different between the two time steps. For that I used ANCOVAs in R (function: aov() ) with the interaction of the nominal variable timestep and depth.

When the interaction between timestep and depth was significant (as in this figure), I interpreted that as (again for this fig): More individuals that had lower values of the biological variable were in shallower waters (rather obvious), during timestep 2 (dark blue) and that, also in the dark blue dataset,  the biological variable in individuals increased more with depth than in light blue. Also due to more individuals with low biological values in shallower waters in the dark blue dataset.

However, my concern is the following. The maximum possible depths are different at the two time steps (~340 m in time step 1, light blue; ~260m in timestep 2, dark blue). So, the dark blue dataset can never have a datapoint at a depth of s.th. like 300+ m, like the light blue data has. I am not sure if my biological interpretations make sense, taking that into account.

Do my ANCOVAs for this data make sense or should I rescale my depth for all datasets to be between 0 and 1 only for example. I did that for a few cases, and the results were the same.

[image: Figure shows the lineare regressions for dataset 1 and 2, light blue and blue]

According to this source and links within:
http://www.biostathandbook.com/ancova.html

I think what I did was correct and that I do not have to rescale.

Comment: I really don't think it'd make a difference to re-scale, since the two lines cross at about 80 m, that's what makes the interaction significant in your model.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Any more thoughts are more than welcome!